# C# access Textbox of parent form from Listview control class

Tags: c#

I created custom Listview and for usage I need to access Textbox on same Form where Listview is. Currently what I do everywhere in my Listview code is this:

```
 Form frm = FindForm();
 var text_ctl = frm.Controls.Find("Textbox1", true).FirstOrDefault() as Control;
 TextBox Txt = (TextBox)text_ctl;

  ...
  Txt.Text="Test";
```

But instead of repeating same code over and over I want to do It only once, like in OnCreateControl() and pass that reference to everywhere I need It in my Listview class. What is the easiest or most elegant solution for this ? Thanks for help in advance !

Comment: Make that `TextBox` public

Comment: If you don't want to repeat code, why aren't you using a method?

Comment: If this is custom ListView, you can add a property of type TextBox and when form is loaded, initialize that with TextBox control you have on form.

Comment: @SamvelPetrosov, and what next ? Listviw still need to know control name. Beside that I want to save reference once and then use one variable, otherwise I will be on same path.

Comment: @Sandeep, yes that is what I'm looking for, got any examples to show?

Comment: @Sefe, that is what I'm searching for, or property :)

Comment: @Lucy82 if the `TextBox` is public you can use it as `frm.TextBox1.Text`

Comment: What's stopping you? I assume you know how to do a method.

Comment: @SamvelPetrosov, not from Listview class.

Comment: @Lucy82 if you have the reference to the Form in your ListView then you can use the public fields of the form

Comment: @SamvelPetrosov, I don't have, that is why I'm asking.

Comment: @Lucy82 `Form frm = FindForm();` then what is assigned to `frm`  in this line?

Comment: @SamvelPetrosov, doing this line **"Form frm = FindForm();"** and making textbox to public modifier, and then use **"frm.TextBox1.Text"** in my Listview class produces error.

Comment: @Lucy82 can you write me the exception?

Comment: @SamvelPetrosov: **"Form does not contain a definition for "Textbox1" and no extension method "Textbox1"..."**....Anyway I'm posting solution now, I've figured It out, thanks to Sefe & Sandeep, they gave me an idea.

Comment: @Lucy82 you are getting this message because your form which is of type like `Form1` is boxed into `Form` type from which it is inherited

Answer (score 0):

I complicated too much, here is what I did:

```
  private TextBox _Txt;
  public void GetTxt(TextBox ref_txt)
        {
            _Txt = ref_txt;
        }
```

I run **GetTxt()** after Form loads, then listview class has reference to It.

alternative using property:

```
 private TextBox _Txt;
 public TextBox GetTxt
 {
    get { return _Txt; }
    set { _Txt = value; }
 }
```

Thanks for help, specially Sandeep. And sorry for any inconvenience, I got confused a bit...

Comment: @Sefe, thanks, I'll fix that. But i'll rather make what Sandeep suggested, this is basically same as I had.